# target group for multiple containers load balancer AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have 3 containers deployed on ecs and traffic is distributed by an application load balancer, swagger on this individual containers can be accessed via e.g 52.XX.XXX.XXX/swagger.

I need the services to be accessed via for e.g:

```
52.XX.XXX.XXX/users/swagger
52.XX.XXX.XXX/posts/swagger 
52.XX.XXX.XXX/comments/swagger
```

I've tried add the following the loadbalancer rules

```
PATH /users* or /users/
PATH /posts* or /posts/
PATH /comments* or /comments/
```

I get a 404 error when i visit the load balancer dns for example myapp-lb-4283349.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/users/swagger

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not specific. What exactly did you try? What **exactly** is happening? Any errors? What are you target group settings, listeners, ECS service, ...?

Comment: @Marcin when accessed via the browser for example the loadbalancer dns http://myapp-lb-4283349.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com/users/swagger it gives a 404 error.

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve that with AWS Load Balancer alone. AWS LB doesn't re-route traffic based on paths. They just **forwards** the incoming traffic to origin.

Your service should be accessible via `52.XX.XXX.XXX/user/swagger` `52.XX.XXX.XXX/posts/swagger` etc. in order for Load Balancer to forward it. You can't forward (or re-route) your traffic from Load Balancer like this:

```
LB_URL/user/swagger -> IP/swagger
```

The missing `/user/` part is not something Load Balancer can do for you. Update your application itself and add specific routes which you want to listen on.